# What happend with find -exec mv command

Tags: linux, unix, mv

I just called

```
find -name '*.wmv' -exec '{}' ../other ';'
```

where one of the matched files contained spaces like

```
./blabla - Copy/blabla.wmv
```

It returned the message

```
find: `./blabla - Copy/blabla.wmv': No such file or directory
```

Now the source file is gone and in the target directory 'other' there's only a directory called 'blabla.wmv', but it's empty and I can't find the actual file.

I would have assumed that the command would expand to

```
mv './blabla - Copy/blabla.wmv' ../other
```

(with quotes around the source), but even if it expanded to

```
mv ./blabla - Copy/blabla.wmv ../other
```

neither of the files 'blabla', '-' nor 'Copy/blabla.wmv' existed
so that doesn't explain why the source file is gone and the directory 'blabla.wmv' was created. I'd like to know what really happened.

I don't really care about the file much but I want to be sure that it's not floating around somewhere it's not supposed to or overwrote something that's important.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `mv` in your command.

Try:

```
find -name '*.wmv' -exec mv '{}' ../other ';'
```

Filenames with spaces are handled correctly by find.

Comment: That fixed my problem!  I was using similar answers to move my files, but the quotation tics around the braces made things work for me (on OS X, in case that is relevant)